# how to programming partial ordering to Covering relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

our discrete mathematic class,i was'nt really understand partial ordering and covering relation,and what is for. our teacher let us write a code about extracting the cover relation from partial order ,this make me very confused,i see the code on internet,but i dont quite understand ,and i dont know where i should start,i write a find greatst common divisor code GCD，but i dont know what to do with it,where i should start exactly? I need a rough step!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$, i.e. it is a set of pairs of $A$. We often write $a\, R\, b$ to mean $(a,b)\in R$.

A relation $R$ is a partial order, if it is reflexive ($\forall a\in A:a\,R\,a$) and transitive ($\forall a,b,c\in A:(a\, R\, b\, R\, c\implies a\, R\, c$). 
Note that there can be *incomparable elements*, i.e. for two distinct elements $a,b$ we don't necessarily have $a\,R\,b$ or $b\,R\,a$. Hence the name '*partial*'. 
An example is the set of subsets of a base set with $R=\, \subseteq$ (containment), or the set of positive  integers with $R=\, \mid$ (divisibility).

An element $b\in A$ covers $a\in A$ (with respect to $R$), if $a\, R\, b$, $a\ne b$ and there is no intermediate element between them: $\forall c\in A:(a\,R\,c\,R\,b)\implies (a=c \lor c=b)$.

For finite sets, the whole partial order can be reconstructed by its covering relation (basically these are the edges one only has to draw). You can also implement the algorithm by removing superfluous information:

- Assume the base set $A$ and the relation $R$ (as set/list of pairs) is given as input.
- Optionally, you might need to verify that $R$ is reflexive and transitive.
- Delete all pairs $(a,a)$ from (a newly created copy $C$ of) $R$.
- Loop through all pairs of pairs $(a,b), \ (b',c)$ in $C$ such that $b=b'$, and remove $(a,c)$ from $C$.
- Return $C$.